# Trouble using FIFOQueue in Tensorflow C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, queue

I have had some success using this programming format in tensorflow with other ops, but I am unable to get the FIFOQueue to work properly.  The following code will compile and run, but there is never any data placed on the queue.

```
vector<Tensor> outputs;
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();

auto queue = FIFOQueue(root, {DT_STRING}, FIFOQueue::Capacity(4));
auto enqueue = QueueEnqueue(root, queue, {{"test_string"}});
auto queue_size = QueueSize(root.WithOpName("queue_size"), queue);

unique_ptr<Session> session(NewSession(SessionOptions()));
GraphDef graph;

root.ToGraphDef(&graph);
session->Create(graph);
Status status = session->Run({}, {"queue_size"}, {}, &outputs);

if (status.ok()) {
    if (outputs.size() > 0) {
        cout << outputs[0].DebugString();
    }
}
```

The QueueSize always results in zero, if I attempt to use the data in the queue, the program hangs, I presume because the queue is empty.  If you have any clues, please help, I have tried everything I could think of.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually pretty close, but there was some misunderstanding of the nature of the call.  Each of the operations in the graph start from queue, so repeated calls to session->Run requesting the appropriate output are what is needed to effect the action of the queue.  A slightly more detailed example follows.  It pushes two values on to the queue using a placeholder then it checks the size, then pops the two values from the queue.

```
vector<Tensor> result_1;
vector<Tensor> result_2;
vector<Tensor> result_3;

Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();

Placeholder dummy(root.WithOpName("dummy"), DT_INT32);

FIFOQueue queue(root.WithOpName("queue"), {DT_INT32});
QueueEnqueue enqueue(root.WithOpName("enqueue"), queue, {dummy.output});
QueueDequeue dequeue(root.WithOpName("dequeue"), queue, {DT_INT32});
QueueClose close(root.WithOpName("close"), queue);
QueueClose cancel(root.WithOpName("cancel"), queue, QueueClose::CancelPendingEnqueues(true));
QueueSize size(root.WithOpName("size"), queue);

GraphDef graph_def;
unique_ptr<Session> session(NewSession(SessionOptions()));
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(root.ToGraphDef(&graph_def));
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Create(graph_def));

Tensor t(1984);
pair<string, Tensor> val = {"dummy", t};

TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({val}, {}, {"enqueue"}, nullptr));
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({val}, {}, {"enqueue"}, nullptr));

TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({}, {"size"}, {}, &result_3));

TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({}, {"dequeue"}, {}, &result_1));
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({}, {"dequeue"}, {}, &result_2));

int value_1 = *result_1[0].scalar<int>().data();
int value_2 = *result_2[0].scalar<int>().data();
int value_3 = *result_3[0].scalar<int>().data();

TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({}, {}, {"close"}, nullptr));

cout << "returned value_1: " << value_1 << 
       " return value_2: " << value_2 << 
       " size was: " << value_3 << endl;

return Status::OK();
```